# Keycloak error invalid_client Bearer only not allowed

Tags: java, rest, http, keycloak

I'm trying to deploy a very simple REST service secured with keycloak and am getting the following error:

> Caused by:
>   org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpResponse.Exception:
>   Unexpected response from server: 400 / Bad Request / Response from
>   server: ("error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Bearer-only not
>   allowed")

What does this error mean? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you have not shared your keycloak config, I am guessing the above error is because you created a bearer only client in keycloak.
Keycloak doesn't allow "bearer only" clients to obtain tokens from the server. Try to change your client to "confidential" on the server and set bearer-only on your adapter configuration (keycloak.json).

You can refer this thread for more info: http://keycloak-user.88327.x6.nabble.com/keycloak-user-can-we-use-authorization-with-bearer-only-td2123.html

Comment: thanks for the info! Yes, I had set "bearer only" in keycloak. Now, I set it to "confidential." On the client keycloak.json file I added "bearer-only": true. So, now I no longer get the Exception, but my response status is 302. So my "bearer only" problem is solved, but I still have the 302.

Comment: the exception is no longer there. But the response from the keycloak secure service is 302.

Comment: That seems to be a different issue. 302 is for permanent redirect , I guess.

Comment: any hints or suggestions will be helpful!

Comment: You can post it as a separate question with enough details about the configuration and your rest api

Comment: Nice piece of info!

Comment: Why is it an option to set "Bearer-only" for the server side client definition? I also had this problem.